# error: type/value mismatch at argument X in template parameter list

Tags: c++, c++11

Intento crear una *mochila*, una clase plantilla que actúe como *envoltura* de otra, y realize llamadas a un *callable* proporcionado en uno de sus argumentos.

Me gustaría que el *callable* pudiera ser tanto una clase que admita `operator( )`, como una función normal.

Todo el *meollo* del asunto es una única función, `void call( )`. Como C++11 no admite la especialización de funciones miembro, he creado una clase base plantilla, que *oferta* esa única función. En la clase hija es donde estará toda la funcionalidad necesaria.

Al grano. He intentado

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template< typename T, typename F, bool IC, bool IF > struct Base;

// Especialización para VOID
template< typename T > struct Base< T, void, false, false > {
  void call( const T &, signed ) const { }
};

// F es una clase.
template< typename T, typename F > struct Base< T, F, true, false > {
  void call( const T &data, signed inc = 1 ) const {
    static F imp{ };

    imp( data, inc );
  }
};

// ESTO FALLA ESTREPITOSAMENTE.
//
// F es una función
template< typename T, typename F > struct Base< T, F, false, true > {
  void call( const T &data, signed inc = 1 ) const {
    F( data, inc );
  }
};

// Clase real, la que usamos.
template< typename T, typename F = void, bool IC = ::std::is_class< F >::value, bool IF = ::std::is_function< F >::value > struct Test :
public Base< T, F, IC, IF > {
  T value;

  Test< T, F, IC, IF >( ) : value( ) { Base< T, F, IC, IF >::call( value, 1 ); }
};

// Callable de prueba. Una clase.
struct Counter {
  template< typename T > void operator( )( const T &, signed i ) { ::std::cout << "Counter: " << i << "\n"; }
};

// Callable de prueba. Una función no-miembro.
void FCounter( const int &, signed inc ) { ::std::cout << "FCounter: " << inc << "\n"; }

int main( void ) {

  Test< int > t1;           // CASO 1
  Test< int, Counter > t2;  // CASO 2
  Test< int, FCounter > t3; // CASO 3

  //Test< int, []( int, signed i ) { std::cout << "lambda: " << i << "\n"; } > t4;

  return 0;
}
```

Dentro del `main( )` están los casos de prueba actuales. El 1 y el 2 se pasan sin problemas, pero el 3 ...

> prog.cc:40:23: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for 'template struct Test'
>      Test< int, FCounter > t3;
>   prog.cc:40:23: note:   expected a type, got 'FCounter'
>   prog.cc:40:23: error: template argument 3 is invalid
>   prog.cc:40:23: error: template argument 4 is invalid

1. ¿ Como lo hago para el caso 3 ? Usar una función no-miembro.

Y, en un *abuso* ...

2. ¿ Como sería para el caso 4 ? Usar una *lambda*. O, mejor aún, algo compatible con `std::function< void( const T &, signed ) >`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problema.

> ```
> expected a type, got 'FCounter'
> ```

Este error está diciendo que se esperaba un tipo y se le ha pasado una instancia. `FCounter` no es un tipo si no una función, el tipo de `FCounter` es `void( const int &, signed )`. Para transformar una instancia en tipo debes usar el operador `decltype`:

```
Test< int, decltype(FCounter) > t3; // CASO 3
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- void( const int &, signed )
```

Resolver este problema ¡nos da el error opuesto!:

```
template< typename T, typename F > struct Base< T, F, false, true > {
  void call( const T &data, signed inc = 1 ) const {
    F( data, inc );
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- F es un tipo, no una instancia
  }
};
```

Ahora necesitamos una instancia (no un tipo) para hacer la llamada, para ello deberá proveerse en el constructor:

```
template< typename T, typename F > struct Base< T, F, false, true > {
  F imp;
  Base(F f) : imp{f} {}
  void call( const T &data, signed inc = 1 ) const {
    imp( data, inc );
 // ^^^ <--- Instancia, no tipo
  }
};
```

Pero esto hará fallar la clase `Test` porque ahora puede heredar de una especialización que requiere constructor cuando antes no era requerido en ninguna especialización.

#### Solución.

> Intento crear una *mochila*, una clase plantilla que actúe como *envoltura* de otra, y realize llamadas a un *callable* proporcionado en uno de sus argumentos.
>
> Me gustaría que el *callable* pudiera ser tanto una clase que admita `operator( )`, como una función normal.

Entiendo por tus requerimientos que necesitas poder llamar cualquier función con cualquier firma, pero en tu enunciado todas las llamadas son `const T &` como primer parámetro y `signed` como segundo parámetro, así que tu *mochila* podría ser:

```
template <typename type_t, typename function_t>
struct mochila
{
    mochila(function_t function) : f{function} {}

    void call( const type_t &data, signed inc = 1 ) const
    {
        f(data, inc);
    }

    function_t f;
};
```

Por desgracia esa `mochila` no aceptaría funciones libres (no puedes tener un `function_t` que sea una función libre, debe ser un **puntero**) así que debemos especializar para funciones libres:

```
template <typename type_t>
struct mochila<type_t, void( const type_t &, signed )>
{
    using function_t = void( const type_t &, signed );

    mochila(function_t function) : f{function} {}

    void call( const type_t &data, signed inc = 1 ) const
    {
        f(data, inc);
    }

    function_t *f;
};
```

Con estas plantillas, podemos modificar tu ejemplo:

```
mochila<int, Counter> m1(Counter{});
mochila<int, decltype(FCounter)> m2(FCounter);

auto lambda = []( int, signed i ) { std::cout << "lambda: " << i << "\n"; };
mochila<int, decltype(lambda)> m3(lambda);

m1.call(1);
m2.call(2);
m3.call(3);
```

Creando la siguiente salida:

> ```
> Counter: 1
> FCounter: 1
> lambda: 1
> ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tZblyZSORfnA1FgT)</kbd>.

Comment: Efectivamente, no lo indico, pero la firma de cualquier función ha de ser `void( const T &, signed )`. Bien visto :-)

Comment: En el caso de la clase con el operador función no sería necesario pasar una instancia de la clase... solo es necesario en el caso del puntero a función... salvo que se quede así por uniformidad

Comment: @eferion también con lambda, pues las lambda tienen el constructor borrado.

Comment: Ahí faltaba una función similar a `make_unique`... así la función deduce los tipos y te ahorras tener que ponerlos dos veces... pero sí, son esos detalles de C++ que le restan mucha homogeneidad